# What's the simplest way to run Lua 5.3 in a standard browser with maximum compliance?

Tags: javascript, html, lua

I would like to run *LUA* code in my *browser* Safari. I've no idea about how it works, but I know a [web site](http://moonshinejs.org/editor/) that gives me the possibility to write *lua* code and it can compile it, and getting the result.

Any help would be much appreciated! The web site link : http://moonshinejs.org/editor/

Comment: The website you linked to has a pretty solid doc on how to do this. http://moonshinejs.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

The website you used seems to be either a sandbox or a webassembly-based thing.
For what you're asking, there are multiple things I've seen.

<s>A pretty new/maintained one is [lua.js](https://github.com/mherkender/lua.js) (this one works in NodeJS and web. It's also the most maintained. I'd recommend it.)</s> What was I thinking, last updated 4 years ago

The rest are mainly NodeJS, but here anyway:

- [lua-in-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lua-in-js)
- [lua.vm.js](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua.vm.js/lua.vm.js.html)

Comment: lua.js is quite old now, so I suspect that @alexander-misel's answer of fengari or the options in the comments are better.

Comment: The same guy wrote both lua.vm.js and fengari - the github repo fro lua.vm.js says to use fengari-web instead. So see @alexander-misel's answer if you want a Lua virtual machine in js.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the best solution to run Lua inside browser is [fengari](https://fengari.io/) I think. It implements a standard compliant Lua 5.3 VM in JavaScript. It has the same C API written in JavaScript.

I also have a repo [lua2js](https://github.com/AlexanderMisel/lua2js) which supports some basic lua syntax. It uses PEG.js to generate the parser.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading rather than trying, it looks like fengari is the simplest option, while https://yiwei.dev/port-lua-to-web-environment-using-webassembly/ and https://github.com/ceifa/wasmoon both use web-assembly so should be faster.